# How does iZip interact with DropBox?

Tags: ios, ipc, sandbox

How does the iZip application interact with the DropBox app, since they're both sandboxed?

As I see it I have full access to DropBox from within iZip, but I've heard that inter-process communication on iOS is limited.

Does iZip use DropBox's API, or are there different ways to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having full access to the dropbox of a user doesn't require interprocess communication. It's just that the app uses the Dropbox client library for iOS to get authenticated by the user, and the developers of this app requested full access when they were registering their app with Dropbox.

Comment: Do you mean that iZip is a registered DropBox application and it uses existent devices' DropBox connection not the DropBox application?

Comment: @IlyaMatveychikov It doesn't have anything to do with the Dropbox application at all.

Comment: In other words, it uses only the DropBox REST API's and account information?

Comment: @IlyaMatveychikov Yes, exactly.

Comment: Sad news to me. Could you point me is there any way to provide a SOCKS-like proxy service to other applications on iOS?

Comment: @IlyaMatveychikov Private APIs only. You may want to use [this class](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/CPDistributedMessagingCenter).

Comment: I'll suggest that Apple can't allow  such an application to be in the AppStore. Is there any ways to distribute it without JB and Cydia?

Comment: @IlyaMatveychikov Sure, make it an in-house application.

Comment: Point me out what do you use and how can I deploy the application without AppStore?

Comment: @IlyaMatveychikov I've never worked with the official development tools, sorry. I can't give you better advice than distributing it through Cydia.

Comment: We used Cydia for a long time but we want to avoid jail-breaking process. Can I have a PM to you?

Comment: @IlyaMatveychikov Sorry, I don't do private consulting.